# Form and input validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to get two inputs inside of a `form` tag to bring up a error message if you leave either of them blank.

I went to w3schools and tried their code but it does not work. (see below)

HTML

```
<form name="myForm"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Js

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
       alert("Name must be filled out");
       return false;
    }
}
```

I removed the `action="demo_form.asp"` from the code because my teacher told me to

Here is my code
HTML

```
<div class="loginShite">
    <form name="username" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="@Username" /> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> 
        <br />
    </form>
    <div class="loginButton">
        <a href="#homePage">
           <input type ="button" value="login" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["username"]["password"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
       alert("Name must be filled out");
       return false;
    }
}
```

I would be greatly appreciative is somebody could either tell me what I'm doing wrong OR point me in the right direction to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your button type should be "`submit`" and should be inside `</form>` tag.
See the form tag name and see the JavaScript how to get values from form tag.

**Update**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.yourFormName.username.value;
    var y = document.yourFormName.password.value;

    if (x == "" || y == "" )
    {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false; 
    }
} 

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<form name="yourFormName" onsubmit="return validateForm(this.form)" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="@Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <a href="#homePage"><input type ="submit" value="login" /></a>
</form> 

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted all of that into my markup and js and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: BTW i wrapped the last input tag..the type='submit" one in an <a href></a> tag to get to the next page...

Comment: SURE THING!

    <form name="yourFormName" onsubmit="return validateForm(this.form)"   
    method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="@Username" /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

    <a href="#homePage"><input type ="submit"  value="login" /></a>
    </form>



    function validateForm() {
      var x = document.yourFormName.username.value;
      var y = document.yourFormName.password.value;
    
      if (x == "" || y == "" )
      {
       alert("Name must be filled out");
       return false;
      }
     }

Comment: Note to reviewers: If you see this crop up in the queue its because the asker vandalised the answer.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by full html

Answer (score 0):

use `type="submit"` instead use of `type="button"`,it works fine

```
<head>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.forms["username"]["password"].value;
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="loginShite">
        <form name="username" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="@Username" /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /> <br   
                />
            <div class="loginButton"><a href="#homePage">
                 <input type ="submit" value="login" /></a></div> </a></div> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function validate(evt){
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
            key = String.fromCharCode( key );
            var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
            if( !regex.test(key) ) {
                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        function validateForm(){
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
            if(fname == ""){
                alert("Please Enter first name");
                return false;
            }
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
            if(lname == ""){
                alert("Please Enter last name");
                return false;
            }
            var mnumber = document.getElementById("mnumber").value;
            if(mnumber == ""){
                alert("Please Enter Mobile no");
                return false;
            }
            if((mnumber.length <10)){
                alert("Please Enter 10 DIGIT mobile no");
                return false;
            }
            if((mnumber.length >10)){
                alert("Please Enter 10 DIGIT mobile no");
                return false;
            }
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            if(message == ""){
                alert("Please Enter Message");
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="form" id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="fname" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="lname" placeholder="lname" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="mnumber" id="mnumber" placeholder="mnumber" onkeypress="validate(event)" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</html>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i've done it. You need to make sure the input type for button is "submit" else the form will not consider it as a trigger to submit. then you need to use || conditionals to test both the field conditions if they are blank or not. You can secure it more by adding the trim() method to avoid any accidental whitespaces getting accepted

Here's the HTML

```
 <form onsubmit="return validate()" action="" class="form-group">
<div style="margin-top:2%">
  <div class="col-md-4"> // bootstrap
    <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="user name"><br>
    <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><br><br>
    <p id="demouname"></p>
    <p id="succesuname"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the JS

```
function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("uname");
  var password = document.getElementById("pass");
  if (username.value.trim() == "" || password.value.trim() == "") {
    document.getElementById("demouname").style.display = "block";

    document.getElementById("demouname").innerHTML = "No Empty Values Allowed";

    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("succesuname").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("succesuname").innerHTML = "Success";
    true;
  }
}
```

and some basic css for added styling

```
    #demouname {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  background-color: rgba(250, 232, 232, 0.2);
  color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-animation: shadow-drop-2-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: shadow-drop-2-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

#succesuname {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid green 1px;
  background-color: rgba(251, 252, 251, 0.521);
  color: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-animation: shadow-drop-2-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  animation: shadow-drop-2-center 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes shadow-drop-2-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
    transform: translateZ(50px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
  }
}

@keyframes shadow-drop-2-center {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
    transform: translateZ(50px);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you have to do is put `required` at the end of the first `input` tag. For example:

```
<form>
<input type=“text” required>some text</input>
<!—-some other input—->
<input type=button>submit</input>
</form>
```

I believe that should work.

Comment: It won’t be the prettiest, however